# Pass LINQ query to VIewBag to create DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I'm trying to pass a LINQ query to a view bag in order to bring a list from my database and display it in a `DropDownList`.

This is what I came up with:

```
List<SelectListItem> ddCompany = new List<SelectListItem>();
var companyList = (from c in leases.tblvCompanies
                   select new {c.Company_ID, c.Company }).ToList();
foreach(var item in companyList)
{
    ddCompany.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = companyList.Company_ID, Text = companyList.Company });
}
ViewBag.ddCompany = ddCompany;
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Company_ID' and no extension method 'Company_ID'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can somebody help me to figure out why it doesn't work? There is any other way different than this one?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to KiwiPiet and Robert McKee here is what made it work:

Controller:

```
List<SelectListItem> ddCompany = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var companyList = (from c in leases.tblvCompanies
                               orderby c.Company ascending
                               select new { c.Company_ID, c.Company }).ToList();
            foreach (var item in companyList)
            {
                ddCompany.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.Company_ID.ToString(), Text = item.Company });
            }
            ViewBag.ddCompanyList = ddCompany;

            ViewBag.messageString = "ddCompanyList";
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddCompanyList")
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be referencing the list companyList in your loop instead of the singular item:

```
ddCompany.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = companyList.Company_ID, Text = companyList.Company });
```

should be:

```
ddCompany.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.Company_ID, Text = item.Company });
```

I would actually suggest the following:

```
ViewBag.ddCompany=leases.tblvCompanies
  .Select(c=>new SelectListItem {Value=c.Company_ID,Text=c.Company})
  .ToList();
```

Although I usually don't like passing UI elements (SelectListItem) from the controller to the view, that's the view's responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating an anonymous type, can you try the following?

```
var ddCompany = (from c in leases.tblvCompanies
                 select new SelectListItem{ Value = c.Company_ID, Text = c.Company })
                 .ToList();
ViewBag.ddCompany = ddCompany;
```

Comment: Hey Kiwi, thanks for the answer! It compiled, but still not working. "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'ddComapny'.". I tried to declare the ddCompany as a IEnumerable<SelectListItem> but still receiving the same error message

Comment: 'ddComapny'?  is that a typo?

Comment: @AronValencio  That's a different problem.  KiwiPiet's code circumvents your original problem by replacing the code you had with the error completely.  This new error relates to being unable to create a dropdown because of a naming conflict.  Correct the typo (probably in your view) and it should work.  See my answer for your original error.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't using a strongly-typed view? You can pass a view model
between the controller and the view for this purpose. like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{ 
  ...

   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      List<SelectListItem> ddCompany = new List<SelectListItem>();
      var companyList = (from c in leases.tblvCompanies
               select new {c.Company_ID, c.Company }).ToList();
      foreach(var item in companyList)
      {
         //in this line you should use item instead of companyList
         ddCompany.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.Company_ID, Text = item.Company });
      }
      return View(ddCompany);
   }
}
```

And in the view:

```
@model List<MvcApplication1.Models.SelectListItem>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   <span>@item.Value</span>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an anonymous type to your view which is not practical scenario for what you're trying to do - anonymous types are generated as internal. You better use a view model to pass your data and you will not have such a problem anymore.

Comment: You can try a cast on the View: `(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ddCompany`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Pedro! I tried to create List<SelectListItem> ddCompany in my ViewModel, but the couldn't manage to assign the LINQ query to it. How should I do it?